# How to set up different start url for Ionic PWA app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I would like to know by any chance I can differentiate the PWA pages from mobile browser and PWA app. My requirement is to show a different page on with the information to Add to Homepage option when app opened on mobile browser once the user added the App on homepage then it should act as normal mob app.

I see there is a start url given on manifest and I tried to change it with no expected outcome... Pls let me know how to do it.. any practical example would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `start_url` is the correct way to do this. For example `"start_url": "/?source=pwa"`. Keep in mind though that for a PWA installed via a browser you will generally have to uninstall the PWA shortcut and install it again for the `manifest.json` cached on the device to update.

Comment: Thanks.. that helped